# Faux Anodized Aluminum Effect

Tags: painting

I'm looking for a spray paint that can simulate the look of black anodized aluminum. I will be doing this on wood, the wood is already primed so that there is no wood grain showing. The main problem I have is that black anodized aluminum is not really flat black and it is not really a satin black either, it's somewhere in between. I don't have the equipment to do custom color mixing , any suggestions? Thank you !

Comment: I like "semi-gloss", but I really thought anodized aluminum was a flat finish. I guess the perceived sheen (or lack of) could depend a lot on the surface texture of the anodized material; rough cast would look flat, maybe smooth machined aluminum would look less flat.

Answer (score 1):

My standard "must get this look" finishing advice - prepare several scrap pieces exactly as you have prepared the primed wood, and test the entire finish process on them. Practice makes perfect, and practicing on the final object makes a mess out of it.

My gut guess (and it's a guess, not experience in creating your precise finish) depending on exactly what sort of black aluminum finish appearance you seek would be to undercoat with aluminum paint or light gray primer, and then spray with "transparent black" (or paint with a clear finish with a compatible black dye mixed in.) If trying to match a brushed aluminum look, some texturing of the base coat might help. Steel wool or non-woven abrasive pad after the finish has hardened might help get the surface/shine right.

Comment: I like the aluminum undercoat that should help get it close I was thinking white but your way should do it +